# why is the $Spa(A,A^+)$ spectral?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Where can I find a detailed proof for: $Spa(A,A^+)$ spectral? ($(A,A^+)$ is a Huber pair)

Comment: It's in Huber's paper continuous valuations something something.